# Xamarin Add TouchRecognizer to every cell

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have created a Grid in my MainPage and I have an array with strings (image sources). Now I want to add foreach string a Image to the Grid, but there can only be 2 images in 1 row, so i need to add rows when needed. Also, each image must be clickable!

Here is my Grid code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ImageGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

</Grid>
```

Now foreach 2 images I want to add these rows:

```
<RowDefinition Height="10" />
<RowDefinition Height="100" />
```

And the images must be placed in column 1 and 3.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but as far as i can understand your problem,this must work:

```
        string[] imageArray = { "image1","image2"...};
        int imageIndex = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) { 
            for(var j = 0; j < column.length; j++)
            {
                if (j == 1 || j == 3) {
                    ImageButton image = new ImageButton { Source = imageArray[imageIndex] };
                    image.Clicked += DoYourWork();
                    ImageGrid.Children.Add(image, j, i);
                    imageIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, only needed to add the j and i variable in this line: `ImageGrid.Children.Add(image, j, i);`